# Unexpected results when using ST_Intersection for polygon features

Tags: qgis, postgis, polygon, intersection

I've to create a spatial intersection of two tables (poly_a and poly_b) containing polygon features. Is there any way to remove unexpected linestring results?

```
CREATE VIEW poly_intersection AS SELECT
row_number() over() AS gid,
subquery.*
FROM
    (SELECT
    (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(poly_a.geom, poly_b.geom))).geom::geometry(polygon, 4326)
    FROM poly_a, poly_b
    WHERE ST_Intersects(poly_a.geom, poly_b.geom) AND NOT ST_Touches(poly_a.geom, poly_b.geom)
    ) AS subquery;
```

[image]

```
ERROR:  Geometry type (LineString) does not match column type (Polygon)
```

I'm wondering about the line geometries because of using `AND NOT ST_Touches(poly_a.geom, poly_b.geom)` in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [ST_CollectionExtract](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html) to pull only the polygonal parts out of the intersection output.

Comment: Shouldn't `AND NOT ST_Touches(poly_a.geom, poly_b.geom)` do this?

Comment: Dimensional collapse during overlay could be causing slight overlaps to turn into boundary touches. Dunno, guessing. Perfection is not available :)